# Select Distinct with Where Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I am trying to get all active Matrix Managers in the `ComboBox`, but what I am getting is `Active` as well as `Non-Active`.

Could anyone help me to correct my query:

```
cmbTL.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
cmbTL.RowSource     = "SELECT Distinct Matrix_Manager FROM EmpMasterTbl WHERE Status='Active'"
```

*Note:* I am using MS Access 2013 DAO.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: If Status was a simple text field, that query would work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want:

```
SELECT Matrix_Manager
FROM EmpMasterTbl
GROUP BY Matrix_Manager
HAVING MIN(Status) = "Active" AND MAX(Status) = "Active";
```

This will get managers that have *only* active status.